# How do you playback live audio in an iPhone?

Tags: ios, audio, playback, microphone

Say you want to playback exactly what the iPhone mic is picking up in real-time.  Which framework/class would be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use the Core Audio framework for this.  Specifically, look into audio graphs, audio units, and RemoteIO.  Plenty of sample code for those to get you started.